# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List error displayed when emitting data from an R bolt to next bolt

Tags: r, integration, apache-storm

I am using an R bolt to process my data.I want to emit the processed data from R bolt to my next bolt ,i.e., CountBolt.But when emitting from an R bolt, **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List** error is shown.

```
 ERROR o.a.s.t.ShellBolt - Halting process: ShellBolt died. Command: [Rscript, permute.R], ProcessInfo pid:7169, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
7055 [Thread-77] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
7145 [Thread-58-sentence-spout-executor[27 27]] INFO  o.a.s.d.task - Emitting: sentence-spout default [the cow jumped over the moon]
7145 [Thread-58-sentence-spout-executor[27 27]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 25 tuple: source: sentence-spout:27, stream: default, id: {}, [the cow jumped over the moon]]
7148 [Thread-70-python-split-sentence-executor[25 25]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - Processing received message FOR 25 TUPLE: source: sentence-spout:27, stream: default, id: {}, [the cow jumped over the moon]
7149 [Thread-70-python-split-sentence-executor[25 25]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:522) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:487) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:74) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10795$fn__10808$fn__10861.invoke(executor.clj:861) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__553.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.execute(ShellBolt.java:175) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10795$tuple_action_fn__10797.invoke(executor.clj:739) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__10716.invoke(executor.clj:468) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__10135.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.die(ShellBolt.java:292) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.access$400(ShellBolt.java:72) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:364) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 1 more
7150 [Thread-70-python-split-sentence-executor[25 25]] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:522) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:487) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:74) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10795$fn__10808$fn__10861.invoke(executor.clj:861) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__553.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.execute(ShellBolt.java:175) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10795$tuple_action_fn__10797.invoke(executor.clj:739) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__10716.invoke(executor.clj:468) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__10135.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: pid:7212, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.die(ShellBolt.java:292) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.access$400(ShellBolt.java:72) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:364) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 1 more
7246 [Thread-58-sentence-spout-executor[27 27]] INFO  o.a.s.d.task - Emitting: sentence-spout default [an apple a day keeps the doctor away]
7246 [Thread-58-sentence-spout-executor[27 27]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 24 tuple: source: sentence-spout:27, stream: default, id: {}, [an apple a day keeps the doctor away]]
7248 [Thread-30-python-split-sentence-executor[24 24]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - Processing received message FOR 24 TUPLE: source: sentence-spout:27, stream: default, id: {}, [an apple a day keeps the doctor away]
7248 [Thread-30-python-split-sentence-executor[24 24]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - Execute done TUPLE source: sentence-spout:27, stream: default, id: {}, [an apple a day keeps the doctor away] TASK: 24 DELTA: -1
7254 [Thread-75] ERROR o.a.s.t.ShellBolt - Halting process: ShellBolt died. Command: [Rscript, /home/uvionics/Downloads/Dixon/Rstorm/src/jvm/udacity/storm/resources/permute.R], ProcessInfo pid:7170, name:python-split-sentence exitCode:-1, errorString: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
7254 [Thread-75] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer.readShellMsg(JsonSerializer.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:125) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
```

The below code represents the code for SentenceWordCountTopology

```
package ***.storm;
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;

import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils;

import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import ***.storm.spout.RandomSentenceSpout;
import ***.storm.SplitSentence;

public class SentenceWordCountTopology {

  private SentenceWordCountTopology() { }

  static class CountBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

    // To output tuples from this bolt to the next stage bolts, if any
    private OutputCollector collector;
    PrintWriter fOut;
    String outFile;

    // Map to store the count of the words
    private Map<String, Integer> countMap;

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple)
    {
         try {
              if(fOut == null) {
                   fOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
               }

              String key = tuple.getStringByField("key");
              String value = tuple.getStringByField("value");

              //fOut.println("FROM STORM:" + count + ":" + tuple.toString()); 
              fOut.println("FROM STORM:" + ":(" + key + "," + value + ")");
              fOut.flush();

      } catch (IOException ioe) {
             System.out.println("Writing to file:" + outFile + " failed");
      }
        System.err.println("++++++++++++++++++ " + tuple);

        countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

      //Syntax to get the word from the 1st column of incoming tuple
      String word = tuple.getString(0);

      // check if the word is present in the map
      if (countMap.get(word) == null) {

      // not present, add the word with a count of 1
      countMap.put(word, 1);
      } else {

      // already there, hence get the count
      Integer val = countMap.get(word);

      // increment the count and save it to the map
      countMap.put(word, ++val);

    }
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer)
    {
      outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("word","count"));
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        outFile = config.get((Object)"ALLFILE").toString(); 

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // create the topology
      Config config = new Config();
        config.setDebug(true);
        config.setNumWorkers(1);
                config.put("ALLFILE",(Object)"/path/new.txt");

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("sentence-spout", new RandomSentenceSpout(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("python-split-sentence", new SplitSentence(), 10).shuffleGrouping("sentence-spout");
    builder.setBolt("count-bolt", new CountBolt(), 15).shuffleGrouping("python-split-sentence");

    LocalCluster cluster=new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("pc", config, builder.createTopology());
    Thread.sleep(40000);
    cluster.shutdown();
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("pc", config, builder.createTopology());

  }
}
```

The below code represents the code for SplitSentence

```
package ***.storm;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

  public class SplitSentence extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public SplitSentence() {
        super("Rscript", "/path/permute.R");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields());
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The below code represents the code of permute.R

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(permute,quietly=TRUE)
# library(Storm,quietly=TRUE)
source("/path/Storm.R")

storm = Storm$new();

storm$lambda = function(s) {

  t = s$tuple;

  words = strsplit(unlist(t$input[1]),"\\s+",perl=TRUE)[[1]];
  words1 = toJSON(words)
  words2 = charToRaw(words1)

  t$output = vector(mode="character",length=1);
  t$output[1] = paste(c("PERMUTE",words[shuffle(length(words))]),collapse=" ");

  s$emit(t);

};

 storm$run();
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you posted has the exception coming from https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.2/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/multilang/JsonSerializer.java#L135. That line is trying to read the "tuple" property on your spout.

Storm multilang talks to your bolt via stdin and stdout. When your bolt process emits a tuple, it should write something like the following to stdout:

```
{
    "command": "emit",
    // The ids of the tuples this output tuples should be anchored to
    "anchors": ["1231231", "-234234234"],
    // The id of the stream this tuple was emitted to. Leave this empty to emit to default stream.
    "stream": "1",
    // If doing an emit direct, indicate the task to send the tuple to
    "task": 9,
    // All the values in this tuple
    "tuple": ["field1", 2, 3]
}
```

Note how the "tuple" field is a list.

The issue you are seeing is because when your bolt writes to stdout, it writes a string in the "tuple" field. You will need to look at the Storm R package to figure out why this happens.

Since the multilang protocol is text based, you can debug your bolt by manually starting your R program and writing messages to it via stdin. The protocol is described at http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.2/Multilang-protocol.html, see the "Bolts" header.

**Original answer:**

There are a couple of things wrong:

- You need to declare which name you want the output field to have. So `declarer.declare(new Fields());` needs to be `declarer.declare(new Fields("key", "value"));`. Just to explain what this is for, output field names are used in downstream bolts to refer to the field, and in fields grouping to partition by the field. The output fields in the split bolt should match the fields you read in the CountBolt (i.e. "key" and "value")
- **Update: Never mind this point, it is wrong** You aren't emitting properly. The `emit` method signature is `emit(Tuple, List<Object>)`, where the Tuple is an anchor (used to tie the new tuple to the input tuple for acking), and the list contains the values you want the new tuple to contain. There are other `emit` overloads, but they follow this basic idea. Since you've set up your topology so the split bolt emits into the count bolt, you want to emit a key and a value from the split bolt. For example `emit("myKey", 52)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the format for emitting from R bolt is s$emit(t) right? We are still getting the error **org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException:Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken!No output read .**

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Looks like the syntax for the R integration is as you describe, going by the manual at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Storm/.

Comment: Any idea on how to make R and storm integration flawless?

Comment: Yes, make sure the R package follows the multilang protocol I linked above. You'll need to go look at the code of the R package to figure out why it sometimes doesn't.